# Unable to search for user using parse.com query and javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and the JavaScript SDK, I want to create a query that checks if a user is already existing.

There is example code here, which I've adopted and turned into the below code block. I'm getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined` error, which I don't understand why?

https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#users

```
var friendFinder = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo(username, "d"); // find users that match
query.find({
    success: function (friend) {
        if (friendName.length) {
            console.log("Success")
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        //Show if no user was found to match


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot quotes on the "username" field:

```
var friendFinder = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", "d"); // find users that match
query.find({
    success: function (friend) {
        if (friendName.length) {
            console.log("Success")
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        //Show if no user was found to match


    }
});
```